# Let $A, B$ a $3\times\,3$ matrices that sets $\ A^3+5AB=I, A^3-5BA=2I$, find $\det(A) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Need help with this question:

> Let $A, B$ a $3\times\,3$ matrices that sets $\ A^3+5AB=I, A^3-5BA=2I$, find the determinate of $A$.

So I know since $\ A(A^2+5B) = I$, $A$ is invertible and $\ A^{-1} = A^2+5B $, but what next?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right multiply $A^3+5AB=I$ by $A$ and left multiply $A^3-5AB=2I$ by $A$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^4+5ABA=A \\
A^4-5ABA=2A 
\end{eqnarray*}
Add these to get $2A^4=3A$ now take det of this equation.

> $ detA=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: Maybe say left/right multiply rather than pre- and post-multiply. It's a bit clearer.

Comment: Although there are many upvotes on this answer, I think the final result is wrong. It should be $\det A=\frac{3}{2}$ because $\det(cA)=c^n\det A$. Please fix it.